# java test fails because NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, gradle, junit, nosuchmethoderror

I run a test in my environment like this

> ./gradlew test

This is the error I get:

```
securitymanager.ml.pmml.something.SomeTest > test() FAILED
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.dmg.pmml.tree.Node.getScore()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.tree.NodeScoreDistribution.computeResult(NodeScoreDistribution.java:57)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.TargetUtil.evaluateClassification(TargetUtil.java:116)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.tree.TreeModelEvaluator.evaluateClassification(TreeModelEvaluator.java:148)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluator.evaluate(ModelEvaluator.java:535)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluateSegmentation(MiningModelEvaluator.java:512)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluateClassification(MiningModelEvaluator.java:279)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluator.evaluate(ModelEvaluator.java:535)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluate(MiningModelEvaluator.java:212)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluate(MiningModelEvaluator.java:205)
    at securitymanager.ml.pmml.ClassifierImpl.doSomething(ClassifierImpl.java:111)
```

I checked the Node.class and it has the getScore() method.

Any idea??

Comment: paste your code snippet please